# django: same url but different verbs in Classed based view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it good to write urls.py as following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/files/$', FileView.as_view(), name='api-upload'),
    url(r'^v1/files/(?P<pk>\d+)$', FileView.as_view(), name='api-delete'),
    url(r'^v1/files/$', FileView.as_view(), name='api-view-all'),
    url(r'^v1/files/(?P<pk>\d+)$', FileView.as_view(), name='api-view-one'),
]
```

The second one and the forth one are nearly the same. But one is DELETE, the other is GET.

**Any suggestions to improve it? Thanks. Is it possible to reverse the URL by django.core.urlresolvers? just like the following**

['deleteUrl': reverse('upload-delete', args=[instance.pk]),](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/serialize.py#L34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write urls, you just need to define two methods in your view:

```
# views.py

class FileView(...):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # This method will catch the GET call

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # This method will catch the DELETE call
```

With this, you will need only one url config:

```
url(r'^v1/files/(?P<pk>\d+)$', FileView.as_view(), name='api-file')
```

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the URL by django.core.urlresolvers?

Comment: @BAE please, can you give an example of what you want?